# How to make a search list in which element is only shown when user search for its exact value

Tags: javascript, html

So, I have this html code to show a list of numbers:

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="search">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">006372145</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">00021030</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">9123981283</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">190238120983</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">128378</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">1298488</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">12983498</a></li>
</ul>
```

And there is a search bar which a user can type text into. This is the JS code:

```js
function myFunction() {
    // Declare variables
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById('myInput');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

    if(input.value.length == 0){
        ul.style.display = "none";
        return;
    }else{
        ul.style.display = "block";
    }
    // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) == 0) {
            li[i].style.display = "block";
        } 
        else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }

    }
  }
```

It filters the search input to finally match a number but I am trying to make it only show the exact same number without filtering the rest of numbers to see if there is any matching.

For example, I input "00" and no number shows because it's not in the list. But if I typed an exact match to a number in the list it shows then.

Comment: Have you tried filtering with `a.innerText.toUpperCase() === filter`? innerText only returns the textual content (and no html tags). And equals to filter for an exact match

Comment: The `indexOf(filter)` should be **>= 0**  indexOf() returns the index position for the first match.  If you have it as **==0** the filter would only work if the user's text was at the start of the string.  Also, in your code you need to handle what happens if "myInput" is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function applyFilter(userInput){
    /*
      Use css to set the display to none first
    */
    var options = document.querySelectorAll("#myUL > a");
    for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
        if(options[i].textContent.trim() == userInput.trim()){
            // You can also convert to lowercase for more accurate result
            options[i].style.display = "inline";
        }
    }
}
```