# Search Through exel file using a search html

Tags: html

```
function applyFilter(userInput){
    /*
      Use css to set the display to none first
    */
   let allClientIDRows = document.querySelectorAll("ClientID-row > a");
   for(let i = 0; i < allClientIDRows.length; i++){
        let row = allClientIDRows[i]
        let ClientID = row.getElementsByClassName("ClientID")[0]
        if(allClientIDRows[i].textContent.trim() == userInput.trim()){
            //You can also convert to lowercase for more accurate result
           allClientIDRows[i].style.display = "inline";
      }
  }
}
```

This is the function that applys the filter to allow you to search and show what you search for and not the entire form.
i am only looking to show the searched item and not the entire spreadsheet

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Data </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="hero">
        <h1>Type in your ID</h1>
        <h3></h3>
    </div>  
    <div id="display">
        <div id="search">
            <input id="searchClientIDs" Name="searchClientIDs" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for id" />
        </div>
        <div id="noClientIDFound">
            <h2> No ID FOUND </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="loader"> 
            <h4> Loading</h4> 
        </div>
        <div id="allClientIDs">
        </div>
        <div id="errorMessage"> 
            <h2> Failed to get data. Please refresh </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
function setErrorDisplay(loaderElm, allClientIDsElm, errorMessageElm){
            loaderElm.style.display = "none"
            allClientIDsElm.style.display = "none"
            errorMessageElm.style.display = "block"
        }
        
        let allClientIDsElm = document.getElementById("allClientIDs")
        let loaderElm = document.getElementById("loader")
        let errorMessageElm = document.getElementById("errorMessage")
            
        fetch("https://api.apispreadsheets.com/data/").then(res=>{
            if (res.status === 200){
                //sucess
                res.json().then(data=>{
                    const yourData = data["data"]
                    for(let i = 0; i < yourData.length; i++){
                        let rowInfo = yourData[i]

                        let rowInfoDiv = document.createElement("div")
                        rowInfoDiv.classList.add("ClientID-row")

                        let rowClientID = document.createElement("h4")
                        let rowClientIDNode = document.createTextNode(rowInfo["ClientID"])
                        rowClientID.appendChild(rowClientIDNode)
                        rowClientID.classList.add("ClientID")

                        let rowRA = document.createElement("p")
                        let rowRANode = document.createTextNode(rowInfo["RA"])
                        rowRA.appendChild(rowRANode)
                        rowRA.classList.add("RA")
    
                        
                        rowInfoDiv.appendChild(rowClientID)
                        rowInfoDiv.appendChild(rowRA)
                        

                        allClientIDsElm.appendChild(rowInfoDiv)

                    }
                    
                    loaderElm.style.display = "none"
                    allClientIDsElm.style.display = "block"
                    errorMessageElm.style.display = "none"

                }).catch(err => {
                    setErrorDisplay(loaderElm, allClientIDsElm, errorMessageElm)
                })
            }
            else{
                setErrorDisplay(loaderElm, allClientIDsElm, errorMessageElm)
            }
        }).catch(err =>{
            setErrorDisplay(loaderElm, allClientIDsElm, errorMessageElm)
        })
```

This is the HTML part that runs the html search part

For some reason when i run with the function its still showing all the spreadsheet. What i am trying to do is [How to make a search list in which element is only shown when user search for its exact value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64193911/how-to-make-a-search-list-in-which-element-is-only-shown-when-user-search-for-it)

when you type it shows you the result but the form will be empty untiil you type

i tryed with a search function with a filter but it shows the entire spreadsheet. Maybe i am doing something wrong or messed up somewhere in the code.

the applyfilter isnt working for me maybe there is another way i can do this

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all self-closing HTML tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is if your function when running with the forloop correctly, but when it finds the search result it's not updating the HTML view correctly. Needs to update Display property if result found display should be show/inline and if not found Display: none. Please check out the following modified function.

And also you are not passing userInput parameter correctly. I think it's undefined. you can check it out with a console.log.

```
function applyFilter(){
   var searchText = document.getElementById('searchClientIDs').value.toLowerCase();
   let allClientIDRows = document.querySelectorAll("ClientID-row > a");
   for(let i = 0; i < allClientIDRows.length; i++){
        let row = allClientIDRows[i]
        let ClientID = row.getElementsByClassName("ClientID")[0]
        if(allClientIDRows[i].textContent.trim() == userInput.trim()){
            //You can also convert to lowercase for more accurate result
           allClientIDRows[i].style.display = "inline";
        } else {
           allClientIDRows[i].style.display = "none";
        }
  }
}
```